# How to access classic smtp ports from a google compute engine instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-compute-engine, actionmailer

I am using google compute engine instances for a B2B customers, I am developing a feature that would allow customers to use their own smtp servers to send emails built via my application. However, the 3 classic SMTP server ports are blocked by Google (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).
I would like to find the most maintanable way to still access those SMTP servers.
The tech stack is Ruby On Rails / ActionMailer.

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your application is running inside the GCP. Thus, my thought is that you can configure your application to send emails via Google trusted third parties listed on [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/), then your customers should be able to relay their SMTP traffic using 25, 465 or 587 port to your application and send out emails. This is feasible if all servers are running on the same project or connected through [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview), [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) or [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).

Comment: I already use a third party to send emails, but my problem is with using external smtp server that my clients own, they already have a technical stack and will use their own smtp servers to send the emails. And I cannot ask each of them to use a non conventional port. Sorry if the question was not clear.

Comment: As described in the article, GCE does not allow `outbound connections` on ports 25, 465, and 587. Your customers can still send emails to your GCE server (application) on these ports since their connections will be `inbound` to GCE.